# Поиск значения по столбцу таблицы

Tags: c#, .net

Здравствуйте!
В моей программе организован поиск строки в файле, хотелось бы улучшить поиск и сделать возможность поиска по заданному столбцу. Как лучше реализовать данную функцию?

```
    //Дерректива переменной
    static string path = @"F:\test21.csv";
    //Задаем переменную "х" строкового типа
    static string x = "";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            //Заносим значение csv-файла в массив
            string[] sr = new StreamReader(Search.path).ReadToEnd().Split(new string[] { ";", """, ":", "\r" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            Console.Write("Введите значение: ");
            x = Console.ReadLine();
            foreach (string stroka in sr)
            {

                if (stroka == x)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Результат поиска: {0}",stroka);
                    break;
                }

            }

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Press Key to Exit...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: под вопросом есть кнопка `Править`, для правки текста вопроса, воспользуйтесь ей пожалуйста и добавьте какой именно поиск нужен. 1. Что ищем - номер строки в которой есть совпадение с образцом, номер столбца или и то и другое, или просто факт совпадения. 2. Идеально - приложите минимальный пример исходного csv-файла (не надо огромный, достаточно 3х3), образец для поиска и ожидаемый результат. Тогда я смогу быстро дополнить ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
         try
        {
            //Заносим значение csv-файла в массив
            string[] sr = new StreamReader(path).ReadToEnd().Split(new string[] { ";", "\"", ":", "\r" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

            Console.Write("Введите значение колонки: ");
            x = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Введите значение поиска: ");
            y = Console.ReadLine();
            //создаем переменную для сортировки
            int strIndex = 0;
            //выполняем поиск строки
            for (int i = 0; i < sr.Length; i++)
            {
                strIndex = sr[i].IndexOf(x);
                //если strIndex не отрицательное, то выполняем поиск
                if (strIndex >= 0)
                {
                    foreach (string col in File.ReadAllLines(path))
                    {
                        var values = col.Split(';');
                        if (values[i] == y)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Результат поиска: {0} = {1}", x, y);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }

            }

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 3):

> сделать возможность поиска по заданному столбцу

Есть несколько вариантов реализовать поиск в CSV-файле по столбцу.

**1. Используем DataTable**

```
private DataTable CsvToDataTable(string fileName)
{
    var dt = new DataTable("FileData");
    //Если первая строка содержит заголовки столбцов, формируем из нее столбцы таблицы, если нет, придется делать вручную.
    var header = File.ReadLines(fileName).First();
    var colHeaders = header.Split(';');
    foreach(var hdr in colHeaders)
    {
        dt.Columns.Add(hdr);
    }
    //Все строки файла кроме первой заносим в качестве строк таблицы
    foreach(var row in File.ReadLines(fileName).Skip(1))
    {
        var values = row.Split(';');
        dt.Rows.Add(values);
    }
    return dt;
}
```

Таблица сформирована, теперь можно выполнить поиск, например так:

```
var dt = CsvToDataTable("C:\\test.csv");
var findResult = dt.Select("ColName = 'searchText'");
```

В результате получим массив из `DataRow` для которых выполняется заданное условие. Разумеется условие надо писать используя реальные имена столбцов.

**2. Ищем налету без полной загрузки файла**

```
var colIndex = x;//x - номер интересующего столбца, нумерация с 0
var searchText = "searchText";
//пропускаем первую строку, если в ней заголовки с помощью Skip
foreach(var row in File.ReadLines(fileName).Skip(1))
{
    var values = row.Split(';');
    if(values[colIndex] == searchText)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Результат поиска: {0}",stroka);
        break;
    }
}
```

В обоих случаях фокус в том, что при сплите строки из CSV-файла нельзя использовать `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` чтобы не менялись индексы столбцов если отдельные значения в строке пропущены, ну и формат исходного CSV-файла должен быть корректным.

**3. А можно еще как-то?**

Можно. Различных вариантов много, это только примеры возможной реализации, какой конкретно вариант из всех возможных использовать зависит от конкретной задачи.

Comment: Вы дали правильный ответ, просто я хотел его реализовать не много по другому, т.е что бы значение colIndex было не статичным, типа 0,1,2,3, а равнялось найденному значению в массиве, т.е если с помощью цикла for мы определили, что нужное нам значение находится в i-том значении, поэтому и подставляем i. Ниже, в коде, это видно, но работает не совсем правильно.

Comment: удалил свои комментарии как мало информативные

Comment: @Tibomso ничего удивительного, вы же весь файл читаете одной строкой и делаете сплит от нее. В итоге получаете одномерный массив вместо таблицы.

Comment: @Tibomso `File.ReadLines` - это Enuberable, он читает по одной строке за раз. Если уж так хочется сразу все в память, тогда ReadAllLines - посмотрите, он возвращает массив строк. Строка считается до символа перевода строки ("\n" или "\r\n"). csv- двумерный формат и его нельзя читать одной строкой, ну точнее можно но не нужно.

Comment: @Tibomso я о нем и говорил, вы читаете двумерную таблицу в одномерный массив, отсюда и проблемы

Comment: Всё получилось!!!! Спасибо Вам огромное!!!!! Я пытался сделать, как Вы сказали и у меня не получилось, попытался сейчас снова и ВСЁ заработало!!!! А понял в чем было дело, я сравнивал значения "values[strIndex] == y", а надо было сравнивать по i-тому элементу "values[i] == y".

Answer (score 0):

Ответы rdorn и Tibomso  сработают далеко не во всех случаях. Т.к. ответы саппортят далеко не полную спецификацю CSV. А именно:

- Нету поддержки чтения цсв когда в одной ячейке может быть много строк
- Нету поддержки чтения цсв когда внутри ячейки имеется сам разделительный символ (тогда ячейка по спецификации выделяется кавычками)

Если воспользоватся даным ридером CSV файлов:
[Как просто работать с / открыть / изменить / сохранить Excel / CSV файлы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560133/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-excel-csv-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b)

То поиск по конкретному столбцу первого попавшегося значения будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
Csv csv = new Csv();
csv.FileOpen(someFilePath); 

foreach (rowCell in csv.Rows)
{
    //поиск по второму столбцу
    if( rowCell[1].Contains( valueToSearch) )
    {
     //сделать что нужно
    }
}
```

что совсем просто видоизменить под потребности